# ObservableCollection using Move()?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an observablecollection that is associated to a list of items in the 
UI. (The observablecollection is NOT bound to the items in the UI).

Now, the user can choose to multiselect items and re-order them via drag and drop.
So, if i have items  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. as an example, the user chooses 4, 6, 8 and chooses to drop in between say items 1 and 2, then the new list order would be,

1, 4, 6, 8, 2, 3, 5, 7.

How do I use the Move() function to update the list AT ONCE?

If I use move once, the list is already in a different state...? Should I keep track of old indices in a seperate array and then move them? IS that the best way to do this?
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is your aim to raise CollectionChanged event once?

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to raise the CollectionChanged handler only once - you could subclass ObservableCollection (it is not sealed) and add a bool property called RaiseCollectionChanged which you set to true before any silent updates.

The method that actually performs moves inside this collection is protected and virtual - so you can override and check RaiseCollectionChanged before calling base.MoveItem (which raises the event).

It'd also be a good idea to maintain a flag that is marked when modifying the collection in silent mode. That way, when RaiseCollectionChanged is set to true again you can raise the event for all the modified items at once.

Answer (score 0):

Too long post to be in comments, so it is here as an answer.
As **ananthonline** posted, you can subclass ObservableCollection.

But, unfortunately, it will be only half of work. The reason is that collections implicitly use collection views to be bound as items source of items control.

And [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx), which is used as base type for all default collection views in WPF, doesn't support batch collection updates:

```
private void ValidateCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Action)
    {
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
        {
            if (e.NewItems.Count != 1)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(SR.Get("RangeActionsNotSupported"));
            }
            break;
        }
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
        {
            if (e.OldItems.Count != 1)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(SR.Get("RangeActionsNotSupported"));
            }
            if (e.OldStartingIndex < 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get("RemovedItemNotFound"));
            }
            break;
        }
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
        {
            if (e.NewItems.Count != 1 || e.OldItems.Count != 1)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(SR.Get("RangeActionsNotSupported"));
            }
            break;
        }
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
        {
            if (e.NewItems.Count != 1)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(SR.Get("RangeActionsNotSupported"));
            }
            if (e.NewStartingIndex < 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get("CannotMoveToUnknownPosition"));
            }
            break;
        }
        case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
        {
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(SR.Get("UnexpectedCollectionChangeAction", new object[]
            {
                e.Action
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

...and you have to implement ICollectionView. I'm not sure, that this is a right way.